# Ng-bootstrap modal with content from another component

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, components, mean-stack, ng-bootstrap

I am currently developing a web app using the mean stack and been having some troubles using the modal feature of ng-bootstrap. What I want is to show a register modal when the user clicks in the register option of the navbar. I have a navbar component and also a register component, and this is the code I have so far

**register.component.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 ...
 import {NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-register',
   templateUrl: './register.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
 })
 export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    ...

   constructor(
     ...,
     public registerModal: NgbActiveModal
   ) { }
```

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...
import {NgbCollapseModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {RegisterComponent} from '../register/register.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  public navCollapsed = true;

  constructor(      
...
    private regCom: RegisterComponent
    private ngbModal: NgbModal
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  collapseOption(){
    this.navCollapsed = !this.navCollapsed;
    return true;
  }

   openRegister(){
    const modalReg = this.ngbModal.open(this.regComp);
   }

 }
```

I have tried to import the register component in the navbar component but i throws me a bunch of errors that I dont understand since I am a noob in this of programming using the MEAN stack, so if you can help me on how to solve this problem, I would be really grateful.

The error that appears is this:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for RegisterComponent!
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The MEAN stack is not really relevant and technically Angular 2 does not qualify as part of it. Irregardless, this is only related to client side programming.

Comment: Are you import those component in the app.module? The component you used, should be import in the app.module, or feather module.

Comment: Yes, they are all imported in the app.module

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to inject the component into your app through constructor, even though it's not injectable(that's why "there is no provider").There is no need for that.

```
constructor(      
...
    private regCom: RegisterComponent // <-- you don't need this
    private ngbModal: NgbModal
    ) { }
```

You don't need to pass the instance of the component class, just the class itself, to the `open` method of the `NgbModal` class.

```
openRegister(){
    const modalReg = this.ngbModal.open(RegisterComponent);
   }
```

Comment: That's it! I did this and there is no more errors, but there is a new problem. It looks like that the modal is open, but its not showing up. Something similar is happening with a carousel I'm using in other component. However, this was the solution for my initial problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help. There could be a lot of issues with that symptom, but you should probably start from console errors. :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you will need to add to the app.module the following:

```
@NgModule({
  ...,
  entryComponents: [ RegisterComponent ],
  ...
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need take the input from your parent component

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
....
@Input('sample') childValue: string;
....
getValue() {
    console.log(childValue)
}
```

In your parent html, you may do the following:

```
<your-tag (click)="lgModal.show()"></your-tag>
<your-modal #lgModal [sample]="your_data"></your-modal>
```